# Decided and arranged: "He is being..." vs. "He will be in the office on Monday morning."

Tags: present-continuous, future-time

According to my "Cambridge - English Grammar in Use" app, Present Continuous ("I am doing") is used for "things" which are "already decided and arranged". The examples are:

> He'**s playing** tennis on Monday afternoon.
>    He'**s going** to the dentist on Tuesday morning.
>    He'**s meeting** Kate on Friday.

Unfortunately, there is no example with the verb "to be".

Provided that "he" has decided and arranged *to be* in the office on Monday morning, and according to the explanation above, it must go like:

> He'**s being** in the office on Monday morning.

But this sentence sounds weird to me.

Furthermore, the Google Books Ngram search by ["he's being in,he is being in,he's being at,he is being at"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%27s%20being%20in%2Che%20is%20being%20in%2Che%27s%20being%20at%2Che%20is%20being%20at&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20is%20being%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20being%20at%3B%2Cc0) results in *"Ngrams not found: he's being in, he's being at"* or in extremly few hits for *"he is being in"*/*"he is being at"* not corresponding to my schema *"to be in/at some place"*.

**Hence my question:**

Are the sentences

> He'**ll be** in the office on Monday morning.
>   He'**s going to be** in the office on Monday morning.

the only possible forms in this case?
If so, then there is no possibility to express "decided **and arranged**" with "to be"? According to the app *"he's going to do"* expresses the decision that may be arranged, but may be not; and *"he'll do"* expresses a decision made right now.

Comment: An alternative is *He is going to be ...*

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks for the hint. I've incorporated it into my question to express my request clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The verb 'be' is a state verb. State verbs are not *usually* used in continuous tenses as they refer to thoughts, emotions, senses etc. Other common state verbs are 'have' (when it means 'own'), want, and know. You can find a list of state verbs [here](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/stative-verbs.html) or you can just google 'state verbs' to find examples.

The examples you cite at the beginning (playing, going, meeting) are all **actions** so these verbs can be used with both simple and continuous tenses.

Note that state verbs can sometimes be used with continuous tenses, especially if we want to emphasize duration or action.

Example: *I've been wanting a Ferrari for ages.* (duration is important)

but some state verbs can't do this...

Example: *I've known him for two years* (not *I've been knowing him for two years*)

Concerning

> According to the app "he's going to do" expresses the
>   decision that may be arranged, but may be not; and "he'll do"
>   expresses a decision made right now.

the app is basically right about 'he's going to do'. For 'he'll do' there are several functions - the app is only giving one of them. For your sentence

> He'll be in the office on Monday morning.

the speaker is most likely using 'will' to state a future fact.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons "**He's being in the office on Monday morning.*" might sound wrong to you.

1. The verb "*to be*" is already in your sentence in the third person form, "*is*".
2. It's not his existence that has been decided and arranged but rather his presence.

   > He'**s staying** in the office on Monday morning.
   >
   > He'**s coming** to the office on Monday morning.
3. [Non-continuous](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/types.html) verbs aren't often used in the "is __ing" construction.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't use BE + BE-ing to express existence-at-place (attendance, whereabouts, location, etc), you won't find BEING in that kind of statement, whether or not it involves notions of scheduled, decided, arranged.

> He **is being** in school on Monday. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

But you do find it expressing a decided and arranged event or intention:

> He **is being interviewed** tomorrow by the *New York Times*.
>
> I **am being** frugal next month. This month, I'm a spendthrift.

As StoneyB commented:

> They **are going to be** unavailable on Thursday.